# How to change disk image's default mount directory on osx

Tags: macos, command-line, osx-snow-leopard, mount

when I double click a disk image it mounts under /Volumes/image-volume-name. I want to change that for a specific image. I know that I can control the directory when mounting from a command line, but I'd really rather have it mount to my specific directory when mounted by simple opening in finder.

Answer (score 1):

you can't if you use plain Apple mounting.

A work round is to create a symbolic link where you want the mount to be and link to the /Volumes/image-volume-name The image will mount under /Volumes but you can access it via the symbolic link path

e.g. in terminal

ln -s /path/where/you/want  /Volumes/image-volume-name

Comment: The reason for my question was that I don't want the mount directory to be inside /Volume, thats was the point ;)

Comment: The net effect is the same ie the data is visible in the directory you want (look at Apple's directories e.g. /tmp and that is a link to elsewhere so is a common way of doing things)